# Retrieve the ID from the person that published a post on a facebook company page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieve the ID from the person who published a post on our company facebook page.

**What I have:**

My account has an analist role on the company facebook page. When on this page, I can see "Published by (Person X)" under the title of the post.

**What I would like:**

Currently I store traffic insights on an inhouse DB by sending calls to the facebook graph API (Reach, likes, ...). I would like to add this "published by ..." person ID to my stored data.

**What I have tried:**

I've looked into the graph API for "posts" [link to doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post/) and tried to retrieve the "from" field and the "admin_creator" field. The from field just returned the name of our company fb page and the admin_creator field gave me the id of the post itself.

Is it possible to retrieve this field by using a Facebook API call? And if so, could someone help me out with pointing out the right field to retrieve?

Thank you for your time

JMordijck

**EDIT:**

added screenshot[image: result for admin_creator]

Comment: Are you talking about a post made “as” the page by an admin, or a normal user post made on the page (in the “posts by others” section)? And that `admin_creator` would return a _post_ id, makes no sense at all.

Comment: we have employees who can publish posts on our company facebook page containing links to articles from our website. So "as" the page by an admin.

Comment: You need to use a page access token to be able to request the `admin_creator` field.

Comment: The id returned when calling admin_creator appears to be a default response when i request a field. So the admin_creator actually returned an empty response

Comment: Yes, I understand what you meant by that now – it is just the normal `id` field that is returned in any case, and the `admin_creator` field just wasn’t returned at all. As said, you need to use a page access token to request it.

Comment: ok ty i'll give that a try and respond with the results

Comment: Changing the user access token to a page access token solved this problem. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBroe mentioned in the comments:

I needed a page access token instead of an admin user access token to retrieve the admin_creator field.

Thank you CBroe for the swift response